# SQL Query - Understanding an error in my query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query - I need help with returning a few more columns.

What I need to return is

- OrderHeader.receiver
- OrderHeader.receiver_name1
- OrderDetail.quantity
- Consignments.despatch_date
- Consignments.connote_estimated_cost

Here is the code that I have at the moment:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        Consignments.consignment_number, UserReferences.value, 
        Consignments.despatch_date
    FROM 
        Consignments
    INNER JOIN 
        OrderDetail ON Consignments.consignment_id = OrderDetail.consignment_id
    INNER JOIN 
        OrderHeader ON OrderDetail.order_id = OrderHeader.order_id
    INNER JOIN 
        UserReferences ON OrderDetail.record_id = UserReferences.record_id
    WHERE 
        Consignments.despatch_date = '2020-04-24'
)
SELECT
    '11' AS RecordType, t.consignment_number,
    '' AS ' ', '' AS ' ', '' AS ' ', '' AS ' ', 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(varchar(255), t1.value)
           FROM cte t1 
           WHERE t1.consignment_number = t.consignment_number
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS senders_reference
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT consignment_number FROM cte t) t;
```

I have attempted to add the desired columns to the SELECT - but when I do it comes up an error - for example:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   The multi-part identifier "OrderHeader.receiver_index" could not be bound.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only way for that query to generate that error is for one of the 'tables' to actually be a view, and the view to have an error.  I suspect, however, you've simplified the query and taken out the source of the error.  Please ensure the query you show here actually generates the error message you quote.

Comment: This is the full error
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "OrderHeader.receiver_index" could not be bound.

Comment: are there `VIEW` in your query ?

Comment: Line 12 does not have that identifier mentioned. Please edit your question to actually show the actual code that actually generated that actual message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing field should be present with `cte` :

```
WITH cte AS
(     SELECT Consignments.consignment_number, 
             UserReferences.value, Consignments.despatch_date,
             OrderHeader.receiver, OrderHeader.receiver_name1
             OrderDetail.quantity, Consignments.despatch_date
             Consignments.connote_estimated_cost
       FROM Consignments INNER JOIN 
            OrderDetail 
            ON Consignments.consignment_id = OrderDetail.consignment_id INNER JOIN 
            OrderHeader 
            ON OrderDetail.order_id = OrderHeader.order_id INNER JOIN 
            UserReferences 
            ON OrderDetail.record_id = UserReferences.record_id
       WHERE Consignments.despatch_date = '2020-04-24'
)
SELECT DISTINCT '11' AS RecordType, t.*,
       '' AS ' ', '' AS ' ', '' AS ' ', '' AS ' ', 
       STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CONVERT(varchar(255), t1.value)
              FROM cte t1 
              WHERE t1.consignment_number = t.consignment_number
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 1, '') AS senders_reference
FROM CTE t;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, now that the UserReferences.value is within the first SELECT statement - I am running into the original issue I had with multiple rows with the same consignment number... any way to remove the first reference to UserReferences.value within the second column and retaining the senders_reference column at the end?